# Cannot publicDecrypt encrypted RSA messaage

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rsa

I can successfully encrypt a message using `crypto.publicEncrypt` but the way back does not work using `crypto.publicDecrypt`. The error message always shows `invalid padding`.

Keys created using:

```
openssl genrsa -out rsa.private 1024
openssl rsa -in rsa.private -out rsa.public -pubout -outform PEM
```

Code:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import crypto from 'crypto';

describe('PublicKeyEncryptor', () => {
  test('PublicKeyEncryptor', () => {
    // Arrange
    //const publicKey = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./src/tests/data/pubkey.pem'), 'utf8');
    const publicKey = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./src/tests/data/rsa.public'), 'utf8');
    const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./src/tests/data/rsa.private'), 'utf8');

    console.log("")
    console.log(publicKey)
    console.log("")

    const messageKey = '0123456789012345';
    const plainText = Buffer.from('Foobar');

    // Act
    // const encryptedString = encryptWithPublicKey(plainText, publicKeyContent);
    const publicKeyObj = crypto.createPublicKey(publicKey);
    const privateKeyObj = crypto.createPrivateKey(privateKey);
    const encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(
      { key: publicKeyObj, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING },
      messageKey
    );

    console.log("encrypted", encrypted.toString('base64'))

    const msg = crypto.publicDecrypt(
        {
            key: privateKeyObj
            , padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING
        },
        encrypted
    );
    console.log(msg)

    // Assert
    // console.log(encryptedString.toString('base64'));
    expect(encryptedString).not.toBeNull();
  });
});
```

Errors/Output:

```
      ....
      encrypted ru/hr/uS8MzWLX69aTrX/Q/NJuFvnxAv9yhKDM3qO2ajCxCJo6Ql5fGwcaxJKhBPe0mP7/dDa/fb5R3MuCc0nH4a9yj6JGK5W97d7qts05CTLNxFvHiHtFNxftuDJoYoCMzXPmoYzk0U4KXFrECRWfdmsfETH/oybE/3qdBARgc=

      at Object.<anonymous> (encryption.ts:47:13)

  ● PublicKeyEncryptor › PublicKeyEncryptor

    error:0200008A:rsa routines::invalid padding

      47 |     console.log("encrypted", encrypted.toString('base64'))
      48 |
    > 49 |  const msg = crypto.publicDecrypt(
         |                     ^
      50 |         {
      51 |             key: privateKeyObj
      52 |             , padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING

      at Object.<anonymous> (encryption.ts:49:21)
```

Comment: For decryption `privateDecrypt()` and not `publicDecrypt()` is required, s. [`crypto.privateDecrypt(privateKey, buffer)`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptoprivatedecryptprivatekey-buffer): *Decrypts buffer with privateKey. buffer was previously encrypted using the corresponding public key, for example using crypto.publicEncrypt()*

Comment: You always have to use `publicEncrypt` together with `privateDecrypt` or `privateEncrypt` together with `publicDecrypt`. Because `public[En|De]Crypt` uses the public key of the keypair and `private[En|De]crypt` uses the private key

Comment: `privateEncrypt()` and `publicDecrypt()` are not intended for encryption/decryption at all, but for low level signing/verifying.